# Android notification button in normal view

Tags: android, notifications

I want to add a pause button and if possible a remove button in the notifications.
Like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

This is my Code for the notification:

```
notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Go!")
    .setContentText("Timer set to " + waitingtime/1000 + " seconds")
    .setTicker("Started!")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notlogosmall);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a custom view, it is like how you show views on a home screen widget:

Look at this method on the Notification Builder

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContent(android.widget.RemoteViews)

Pass it your RemoteView with the two buttons you want in the layout.

small example:

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContent(remoteViews);
```